# How to add sagemaker createApp to user profile executionrole?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sagemaker

I created a aws sagemaker user profile using terraform. I tried to launch the sagemaker studio from the user profile but was confronted with this error: `SageMaker is unable to use your associated ExecutionRole [arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/sagemaker-workshop-data-ml] to create app. Verify that your associated ExecutionRole has permission for 'sagemaker:CreateApp'`. The role has sagemaker full access policy attached to it, but that policy doesn't have the createApp permission which is weird. Are there any policies I can attach to the role with the sagemaker createApp permission, or do I need to attach a policy to the role through terraform?

Comment: Can you find the policy elements of the above mentioned policy and add it to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your execution role does not have any permission boundaries. By default, the SageMakerFullAccess policy allows create app permissions - see this statement -

```
       {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:CreatePresignedDomainUrl",
                "sagemaker:DescribeDomain",
                "sagemaker:ListDomains",
                "sagemaker:DescribeUserProfile",
                "sagemaker:ListUserProfiles",
                "sagemaker:*App",
                "sagemaker:ListApps"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
```

You can add an inline policy such as below to make sure your role has permissions to create app -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateApp",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sagemaker:CreateApp",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess`? If you take a look at this policy, you'll find this as one of the statements:

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sagemaker:CreatePresignedDomainUrl",
                "sagemaker:DescribeDomain",
                "sagemaker:ListDomains",
                "sagemaker:DescribeUserProfile",
                "sagemaker:ListUserProfiles",
                "sagemaker:DescribeSpace",
                "sagemaker:ListSpaces",
                "sagemaker:*App",
                "sagemaker:ListApps"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
```

The `sagemaker:*App` action on `"Resource": "*"` means that the policy actually does have the `sagemaker:CreateApp` permission.

It is a [common guardrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/sagemaker-studio-admin-best-practices/permissions-management.html#common-guardrails) (even listed in the AWS Whitepaper on "SageMaker Studio Administration Best Practices") to limit notebook access to specific instances, and that guardrail denies on the `CreateApp` action. And the recommendation in the whitepaper is to control this at the service control policy level (in AWS Organizations, which you may not have visibility into), with this being an example policy:

```
{
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
         {
             "Sid": "LimitInstanceTypesforNotebooks",
             "Effect": "Deny",
             "Action": [
                 "sagemaker:CreateApp"
             ],
             "Resource": "*",
             "Condition": {
                 "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
                     "sagemaker:InstanceTypes": [
                         "ml.c5.large",
                         "ml.m5.large",
                         "ml.t3.medium",
                         "system"
                     ]
                 }
             }
         }
     ]
 }
```